# How to set up a UIView to detect touches (not taps)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to make my interface feel more responsive. A `UIView` changes color on user touch and I want it to do so already when the View is touched. 
I could implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` but a tap is not what I am looking for, since it requires the touch to end before being recognized.

I imagine this to be quite simple. Or am I wrong?

Do I create a custom UIGestureRecognizer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `touchedBegan`?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  if let touch = touches.first {
    // ...
  }
  super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this code? Into a custom UIGestureRecognizer class?

Comment: @Marmelador In your `UIView` class that you want to change color on touch

Comment: Does that mean I don't even need to use a UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Yeah, you can try that. Let me know how it goes.